# Concat / Search on multiple jsonb nested values

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have jsonb column in my PgSql table with data like these :

```
{
  "group": [
    {
      "child1": "test",
      "child2": "test"
    },
    {
      "child1": "test2",
      "child2": "lorem ipsum"
    }
  ]
}
```

"group" can be **multiple** and is **compounded** of nested children data.

Is it possible to concat "child1" data in one select request or to check if one of nested "child1" is like %test%.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the output you want? The whole JSON value for all rows that match the condition? Or only the part of the JSON that matches the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an exists condition:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'group') as g(element)
                cross join jsonb_each_text(g.element) as x(key,value)
              where x.key = 'child1'
                and x.value like '%test%')
```

Starting with Postgres 12 you can use a SQL/JSON path expression:

```
select *
from the_table t
where data @@ '$.group[*].child1 like_regex "test"'
```

Comment: Woww this Pg12 feature is amazing !
Using a path expression will be so helpful.

Comment: Using "cross join" and "exist" together seems to meet completely my need.
Now I have to see how to translate it into ORM language =)

Answer (score 2):

You can use such a `SELECT` statement including two functions with `CROSS JOIN`s:

```
SELECT j2.*
  FROM t
 CROSS JOIN JSONB_EACH(data) AS j
 CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(data->'group') AS j2
 WHERE j2::TEXT like '%"test"%'
```

in order to look strictly for string with exact value `"test"` without any heading or trailing parts. If you need whether that value contains a substring `test`, then get rid of double quotes which wraps up it.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=f693c3ef9367047e622ed09ebe8eeb38)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I did a test and it works. I have to dig a little deeper into the functioning of CROSS JOIN which is not trivial.
And the reason why we use j2.value.

Comment: you're welcome @Benito103e . Nice catch, yes, `value` is redundant.

Comment: With this solution, I also need to add a groupBy if a row has 2 children1 meeting the criteria.